# admob ads doesn't work when uploading the app on play store

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I am using google admob in the app when I used it with the test Id of the project it was working well but when I changed it to the live id the ads stop to come. 
this is my java code :

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.ad_mob_used_id));

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_mob_used_id));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            mInterstitialAd.show();//TODO : check this
        }
    });
```

and this is the code in the manifest :

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/ad_mob_used_id"/>
```

and this is the code in the strings :

```
<string name="ad_mob_live_id">ca-app-pub-1283544791526621~9315704399</string>
<string name="ad_mob_test_id">ca-app-pub-1283544791526621/5955878039</string>

<!-- either live or debug -->
<string name="ad_mob_used_id">ca-app-pub-1283544791526621~9315704399</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below statement, Is it your typing mistake or your mistake ??

You're using same value in `admob_app_id` and `ad_unit_id` !!!

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_mob_used_id)); // use adunit id instead of AD_ID
```

should be

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_mob_live_ad_unit)); //something in format of ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
```

If this is your just typing mistake then wait for a few hours.

Because According to Google :

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and
>   requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start
>   getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads
>   then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you
>   are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID
>   for us to look into."